# How to avoid a jQuery call in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know JQuery is a code smell in ReactJS because it traverses the entire DOM to do it's work.  But, I've found some places where it's hard NOT to use it.  This is one instance where I'd like to find a better way if possible.

I'm just trying to show or hide a message on a div based on whether or not a field is populated...

javascript:

```
if (this.props.loginInfo.userId === ''){
     $("#errorMessageDiv").attr('class', 'visible');
} else{
     $("#errorMessageDiv").attr('class', 'invisible');
}
```

jsx:

```
<div id="errorMessageDiv" className="invisible">
     <h1 id="credentials" className="login-error-message">&nbsp;Please Enter Proper Credentials</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should typically do that by binding the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library.

Basically what it does, adds or removes classnames you like, if you have classnames that has no condition just pass true. See the following snippet.

```
import classNames  from 'classnames'

<div 
  id="errorMessageDiv"
  className={ classNames({
    'visible' : this.props.loginInfo.userId === '',
    'invisible' : this.props.loginInfo.userId !== '',
    'some-other-class-name' : your_condition,
    'will-be-available-definetely' : true
  }) }
>
     <h1 id="credentials" className="login-error-message">&nbsp;Please Enter Proper Credentials</h1>
</div>
```

If you have only one condition, you can do the following :

```
import classNames  from 'classnames'

<div 
  id="errorMessageDiv" 
  className={ this.props.loginInfo.userId === '' ? 'visible' : 'invisible' }
>
     <h1 id="credentials" className="login-error-message">&nbsp;Please Enter Proper Credentials</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I love this!  But, how would I get this to ONLY trigger after a click event?  Is that possible?  Right now the login message is there by default when you load the page.

Comment: Managing a style with an event look complicated and out of scope...  Thanks a bunch FurkanO!!!

Comment: Hmm, you need to change the value when the event fires, so that your condition changes, eventually your classname changes. I can t see no way or need to that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define how the current state renders into view, so you have to bind the condition into the rendering of the error message.

```
var visibleClass = this.props.loginInfo.userId === '' ? 'visible' : 'invisible';
return <div id="errorMessageDiv" className={visibleClass}>
     <h1 id="credentials" className="login-error-message">&nbsp;Please Enter Proper Credentials</h1>
</div>
```