# How to hide and show list contents: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of items, if an item is clicked it shall show its content. Do I need for each list item a `boolean` in the state object or can I do it with add and remove `classname` like in `jquery`?

**Code:**

```
 <ul>
  <li> item <div className="hidden"> some extra text ... </div> </li>
  <li> item <div className="hidden"> some extra text ... </div> </li>
  <li> item <div className="hidden"> some extra text ... </div> </li>
  <li> item <div className="hidden"> some extra text ... </div> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need for each list item a boolean in the state object?

Yes, you need to maintain a `boolean` for each list item in `state` variable, and on the basis of that `state` value, render the content of `list` items, Try this:

```
this.state = {showItems: []}

onClick(index){
     console.log(index);
     let showItems = this.state.showItems.slice();
     showItems[index] = !showItems[index];
     this.setState({showItems});
}

<ul>
  <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,0)}> item {this.state.showItems[0] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null} </li>
  <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,1)}> item {this.state.showItems[1] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null}</li>
  <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,2)}> item{this.state.showItems[2] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null} </li>
  <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,3)}> item {this.state.showItems[3] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null}</li>
</ul>
```

Check this working Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {showItems:[]}
  }
      
  onClick(index){
    let showItems = this.state.showItems.slice(0);
    showItems[index] = !showItems[index];
    this.setState({showItems});
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,0)}> item {this.state.showItems[0] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null} </li>
          <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,1)}> item {this.state.showItems[1] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null}</li>
          <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,2)}> item{this.state.showItems[2] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null} </li>
          <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,3)}> item {this.state.showItems[3] ? <div> some extra text ... </div> : null}</li>
        </ul>
        <div style={{marginTop: 100}}>*click on item to open submenu</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
li{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Check `fiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/18hheyx1/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use react-bootstrap. else you can use state and update it manually.

```
const accordionInstance = (
  <Accordion>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #1" eventKey="1">
      test
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #2" eventKey="2">
     test 1
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="Collapsible Group Item #3" eventKey="3">
      test 2
    </Panel>
  </Accordion>
);

ReactDOM.render(accordionInstance, mountNode);
```

Document : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-accordion

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple to use library, which lets you define conditions on classnames. Library is also called [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

For instance:

```
import classNames from 'classnames'


<li> item 
    <div className={ classNames({
       'some-static-classname' : true,
       'hidden'                : this.state.hiddenItems.includes('itemX')
     }) }
    > 
        some extra text ... 
    </div> 
</li>
```

So this library is only useful to reduce the boilerplate on your conditions. What you need is also keeping the data of hidden/shown items. You might keep this kind of state in react internal state. Then just put your conditions.

Here is another similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267252/4535495) I answered. Hope it helps.