# React toggle read more for each item separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using this code i can toggle `Continue reading` `Read less`, but it works for all items.

How can i **toggle each item in the list separately** ?

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/PKxVpw?editors=1111)

JS

```
handleReadMoreClick(item_id) {
    console.log(item_id)
    this.setState({ readMore: !this.state.readMore })
}


render(....
  let { readMore } = this.state

    <span key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.title}</p>
        <p>{item.date}</p>
        <p className={readMore ? "read-more" : "read-less"}>{item.text}</p>
        <p onClick={() => { this.handleReadMoreClick(item.id) }}>
            {
                readMore ? 
                <strong>Show less</strong>:
                <strong>Continue reading</strong>
            }
        </p>
    </span>
```

CSS

```
    .read-more{
        height: auto;
    }
    .read-less{
        height: 60px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: check this answer: [How to hide and show list contents onClick of list items ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197834/how-to-hide-and-show-list-contents-onclick-of-list-items-reactjs/42197948#42197948)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are having one flag for all components. Instead you should have 1 flag for every item.

Best way is to create a component and then loop over data and create list of components.

```js
class ToggleText extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      readMore: false,
    }
  }
  
  handleReadMoreClick() {
    this.setState({ readMore: !this.state.readMore })
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <span key={this.props.id}>
        <p>{this.props.title}</p>
        <p className={this.state.readMore ? "read-more" : "read-less"}>{this.props.text}</p>
        <p onClick={() => { this.handleReadMoreClick(this.props.id) }}>
          <b> { this.state.readMore ? 'Show less' : 'Continue reading' }</b> 
        </p>
      </span>
    )
  }
}

const Application = () => {
    let news_and_updates = [{"id": 1,"title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary","date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM","text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.","link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879" }, {"id": 2,"title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary","date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM","text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.","link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879" }, {"id": 3,"title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary","date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM","text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.","link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879" }]
    
    return (
      <div>      
        {
          news_and_updates.map((item) => <ToggleText {...item} /> )
        }
    </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.read-more{
  height: auto;
}
.read-less{
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is keeping the `readMore` state in the `Application` component, which means that all your subitems share the same state. Thus, toggling one changes all the items.

You should extract the subitems into a separate component, and have them all have their unique state, which is toggled only when you click on that particular item.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It makes sense, but i would really appreciate an example or a some more details. Can't think of how could i transmit the state to each item and more i feel this is a great pattern that i must learn @_@

Answer (score 0):

Add one property to the item object and use that property to check whether item is readMore or read-less.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      readMore: false,
      news_and_updates : [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary",
        "date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.",
        "link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary",
        "date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.",
        "link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Update: 1st Year Anniversary",
        "date": "09/15/2016 02:36AM",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum erat ut pulvinar tristique. Cras non dui volutpat, imperdiet arcu nec, commodo odio. Fusce sed consequat felis. Cras ut dapibus risus. Phasellus lectus odio, iaculis eu augue et, porttitor ultricies neque. Mauris dapibus ipsum arcu, non commodo ipsum fringilla a. Morbi gravida mi elementum pretium facilisis. Maecenas sit amet dui auctor, malesuada sapien id, ullamcorper tellus. Mauris condimentum posuere eros at commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique sem.",
        "link": "https://www.nutaku.net/games/flower-knight-girl/news-updates/info/879"
      }
    ]
    }
  }

  handleReadMoreClick(item_id) {
    console.log(item_id);
    const news_and_updates = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.news_and_updates)); 
    news_and_updates[item_id].readMore = !news_and_updates[item_id].readMore;
    this.setState({ news_and_updates });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>      
        {this.state.news_and_updates.map((item) => {
          console.log('readMore',item.readMore);
          return (
            <span key={item.id}>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <p className={item.readMore ? "read-more" : "read-less"}>{item.text}</p>
              <p onClick={() => { this.handleReadMoreClick(item.id) }}>
                {
                  item.readMore ?
                    <b>Show less</b> :
                    <b>Continue reading</b>
                }
              </p>
            </span>
          )
        })}
    </div>
    )
}
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```